# Orders X third person verb?

Tags: verbs, to-infinitive, conjugations

I came across this title: [EU on brink: Emmanuel Macron squirms as Donald Trump orders France **leaves** EU](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1139427/brexit-news-emmanuel-macron-donald-trump-france-eu-washington-post-RTS-video/amp).

I'm wondering whether it is a matter of sloppiness or simply I'm wrong. My ear would have wished it to have been:

> Emmanuel Macron squirms as Donald Trump orders France **to leave** EU

Please let me know the reason that they published the title as such.

Comment: News article titles are notorious for weird grammar and skipping over words. You are right in your edit, but I also wouldn't have been surprised if the headline read "Macron Squirms, Trump Orders France Leave EU" (I think they might have chosen leaves because France is singular?)

Comment: It's just news articles trying to save space for headlines - you have the correct meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title makes sense if you imagine they skipped "that" before France:

> Emmanuel Macron squirms as Donald Trump orders *that* France leaves
>   EU.

Another example:

> The court ordered that he leaves Antigua on Thursday. ([Jamaica Observer](http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/latestnews/one_of_jamaica%26%238217;s_most_wanted_arrested_in_antigua?profile=1228))